# optimization jQuery for IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-selectors

I have function:

```
function doBlamingItem($cell, showEditMark) {
    $cell.hover(function () {
        $cell.toggleClass('clickable-cell', showEditMark).toggleClass('editing-cell', !showEditMark);
    }, function() {
        $cell.removeClass('clickable-cell editing-cell');
} );};
```

in $(document).ready() I apply this function for some cells in my table (~500) and when I move my mouse upon it - in FF or Chrome all is okay, but IE7-9 starts lagging and I don't know how to fix it :(

and code from $(document).ready():

```
var i = firstRowOnPage();
while (table.GetRow(i) != null) {
    if (condition) {
        var row = table.GetRow(i);
        var elementInCellId = column.fieldName + '_' + rowKey;
        var $cell = $(row.cells[realIndex]).attr('id',elementInCellId);
        doBlamingItem($cell, true);
        setClickable(editInfo, $cell);
    }
i++;
}
```

I use doBlamingItem for every cell because for some of them showEditMark=true, for other showEditMark=false

Comment: Sorry I can't help, but I do want to say that your English, at least in this question, does not seem terrible :)

Comment: are you sure you do not apply 500 event handlers to each element?!

Comment: Please show the code that calls this function.

Comment: be conscious that IE is sadly still a bit slower than competition. Moreover, tables are very special in html-dom world. [this jsperf test case](http://jsperf.com/sizzle-vs-queryselector/3) is nice example (among tons of other cases on jsperf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code basically (1) finds those ~500 elements, (2) iterates them to (3) assign hover events (consisting of mouseenter and mouseleave). Have you heard of [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)?

The setup time is virtually none (only 2 event handlers, instead of 1000 are registered). No elements are selected and traversed.

```
(function($, undefined){
  // if you want it global
  var showEditMark = true;
  // otherwise save that state to some element's data()

  $(function(){
    $(document.body).delegate('.your-table-selector td', {
      mousenter: function(e){
        $(this)
          .toggleClass('clickable-cell', showEditMark)
          .toggleClass('editing-cell', !showEditMark);
      },
      mouseleave: function(e){
        $(this).removeClass('clickable-cell editing-cell');
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I use `doBlamingItem` for every cell because for some of them `showEditMark=true`, for other `showEditMark=false`

Comment: You might still use the same event handler for all of them, and that event handler will have to check whether `showEditMark` is `true` or `false` for the given cell.

Comment: I changed my code to using delegate and created global array: window.flags[cellID] = showEditMark; but now my page starts lagging more before :(

Comment: I'd have to see the code to tell you what you did wrong… I'm wondering why you are using a global variable instead of [$.fn.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) or simple classes, for that matter.

Comment: because with global array this code is working faster that the $.data()

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who answered my question, but as I realized problem was not in javascript... My page has big DOM-tree of elements and many CSS-styles, so IE has problems with rendering of it